# Installation of driver from ati-driver-installer-10-12-x86.x86_64.run

Tags: installation, drivers, ati

I have installed "Additional Drivers" but there is a problem with ATI Catalyst Control Centre:

> There is no ATI graphics driver installed or it is not functioning properly

I have downloaded the appropriate `ati-driver-installer-10-12-x86.x86_64.run` file from the ATI site. What terminal commands do I need to use to install from this file?

Answer (score 3):

```
chmod +x ati-driver-installer-10-12-x86.x86_64.run
sudo ./ati-driver-installer-10-12-x86.x86_64.run
```

you can also try `sudo sh ati-driver-installer-10-12-x86.x86_64.run` instead of the second line above

Comment: @ECloudh Don't forget to accept this answer as the solution! (Check the little checkmark)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before, I found this [wiki site](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page) that has a comprehensive guide quite helpful, even though it is not official ATI link directly to it from the driver download site.